# Fill empty columns with 0

Tags: awk

I have a file with this structure:

```
1   11827796    2   300 T:0.96  C:0.04  T 
1   11827816    1   300 G:1 G
```

For lines in the file that have 6 columns instead of 7, I would want to insert a zero between the 5th and 6th column so have this output:

```
1   11827796    2   300 T:0.96  C:0.04  T
1   11827816    1   300 G:1     0   G
```

Any idea on how I can achieve this with awk.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: How do you know which column is empty ?

Comment: In other words, for the lines that have 6 instead of 7 columns, I would want to add another column as 0 as the 6th column and move the 6th column to the 7th.

Comment: So its always the 6th column that is missing ?

Answer (score 1):

Here one solution:

```
awk 'NF==6 {$5=$5" 0"}1' file |column -t
1  11827796  2  300  T:0.96  C:0.04  T
1  11827816  1  300  G:1     0       G
```

If there are only `6` fields, add `0` and fix column width.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your "columns" are tab-separated, which it looks like they are:

```
$ awk 'NF<7{sub(/[^\t]+$/,"0\t&")}1' file
1       11827796        2       300     T:0.96  C:0.04  T
1       11827816        1       300     G:1     0       G
```